# Можно сделать так?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Можно сделать так?

```
<?php
   $title = "<?php echo title('id_title_sql'); ?>";
?>
```

Или так

```
<?php
   $title = "<?php echo $title['id_title_sql']; ?>";
?>
```

Как можно сделать помогите я новичок!? Мне нужно поставить результат SQL. 
Например:
`<title><?php echo $title ?></title>`

Comment: Вы зачем php-код обрамляете в php-код? Достаточно просто написать:

    <?php echo $title['id_title_sql']; ?>

если $title это массив. Либо использовать ваш последний пример, т.е.:

    <?php
        $title = 'my title';
    ?>
    <title><?php echo $title; ?>

А вообще в логах надо ошибки смотреть, чтобы понять, на что именно ругается.

Или вам на странице надо пример php-кода вывести без его исполнения?

Comment: @BOPOH, мне поставить здесь`<?
      if ($ispage) {
                     request, return json object with page pieces
       $content = ob_get_clean();
       echo json_encode(array(
        "title" => $title,
        "content" => $content
       ));
      }
       
     ?>`

Comment: Вы бы привели в вопросе пример кода, который не понимаете, а не его часть. По вашему комментарию + вопросу так и не понял, что хотите. Вам надо title заполнить? Так сделайте просто:

    $title = title('id_title_sql'); // если title это функция
    $title = $title['id_title_sql']; // если title это массив

Comment: @BOPOH, Работает, спасибо, у меня функция!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

<pre>
КОД
</pre>

Comment: Не работает!

Comment: print_r и прочие пробывали?

Comment: @Ololoevv, пожалуйста, подробно раскажите! Покажите как?

Comment: <xmp> CODE </xmp>

Comment: @Ololoevv, не работает, покажите через print_r ?